# Is it possible getting array from singe cell?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have table like below:

```
folder     Paths
788       "01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg","06.jpg..........
332       "01.jpg"...................
333       "01.jpg","02.jpg"...........
```

Want JSON output like below:

```
{
"folder": "788",
"Paths": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
},
{
"folder": "333",
"Paths": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is. Storing values as csv is very bad db design.

Comment: use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to store values in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Parse it as you need, in your scenario, [explode](http://php.net/explode) will make your work much easier, see usage below:-

```
$nArray = array();
foreach($arr as $value){

    $nArray[] = array('folder' => $value['folder'], 'Paths' => explode(",", $value['Paths']));
}
```

but, if possible, I would suggest you to change your db structure, and take out `paths` column in separate table, so there would be two tables,

- Folders (each row contains id and name, or more as per needs)
- Paths (each row contains id, folder_id and path, or more as per needs)

Comment: I can change my database structure but I want  same output. So I dont wanna open another topic could you write the sql commands. I mean just json part. Lets say Folders table has id, folder_name. Paths table has id, folder_name,path. SQL command `SELECT Folders.folder_name, Paths.path FROM Folders JOIN Paths ON ........ ` Like this? And then do while loop wtih fetch_assoc?

Comment: `SELECT Folder.id, Folder.name, group_concat(Path.path) path from folders Folder INNER JOIN paths Path ON Folder.id = Path.folder_id
group by Folder.id`

do json_encode($nArray); to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Take that table into array your table will look similar to $array and do this.

```
   <?php
    $array = array(array('folder' => '788', 'Paths' => '"01.jpg", "02.jpg", "03.jpg", "04.jpg", "05.jpg"'),array('folder'=>'332','Paths'=>'01.jpg'));
    $output = "";
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $output[] = array('folder' => $val['folder'], 'Paths' =>  explode(",",$val['Paths']));
        }
    }
    if (is_array($output)) {
        $output = json_encode($output);
    }

echo $output;
?>
```